# Alphabetize Arabic and Japanese text that is in Unicode?

Tags: ruby, sorting, unicode

Does anyone have any code for alphabetizing Arabic and Japanese text that is in Unicode?  If the code was in ruby that would be great.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do specifically with the iPhone.

Comment: The Arabic and Japanese character's are part of the Arabic, Japanese Alphabet. I think some people could take your question as an insult.

Comment: @johannes: I don't think "alphabetize" means "converting to an English alphabet", but "sorting in an appropriate order".

Comment: My understanding is that both Arabic and Japanese alphabets each have an alphabetical order.  I have translated an iPhone app into both Arabic and Japanese and I would like to organize the translated items in an alphabetical list in each of these two languages.

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using? 1.8 or 1.9?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unicode code points are not listed in alphabetic order (Z < a, for example), but they try to be approximately in that order anyway. There is a canonical unicode order, defined by the [Unicode Collation Algorithm](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/) and they are also language-specific ordering (french order is not exacly the same as german or czech order, even with the same alphabet), which can be specified in locale information. I think the [ICU library](http://site.icu-project.org/) contains the language specific algorithms you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Ruby, but python has a function, ord() that translates a unicode special character to its unicode code point. For example,

```
>>> a = u'ل'
>>> ord(a)
0: 1604
>>> b = u'ع'
>>> ord(b)
1: 1593
```

Look for something like that in Ruby. I assume that the Arabic symbols are listed in unicode in alphabetic order.

Comment: Would this help with this question? If we did this to ordinary Latin characters, it'd mean letters would be sorted into being upper or lower case first, which wouldn't make sense in some situations.

Comment: Right, if that applies to Arabic and Japanese too, I guess the OP would have to account for that.

Answer (score 0):

To ask the obvious question, what don't you like about `mylist.sort`?

Comment: Does mylist.sort work with Unicode and knows the alphabetical order of the Arabic or Japanese alphabet?

Comment: ...why don't you try it and see?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs `words.sort` in ruby will be fine for Japanese. The order the characters appear in Unicode are in a reasonably good sorting order. Can't vouch for Arabic though, but my guess is that it's ok as well.

Answer (score 0):

`mylist.sort` should work out of the box in Ruby 1.9 (which has built-in unicode support). In Ruby 1.8, where Unicode support isn't built in, I think you'd have to use the `character-encodings` gem extend the String class with UTF-8 string comparisions. (And then `mylist.sort` would work.)